# R::officer cannot finds rows or id in powerpoint slide

Tags: r, powerpoint, officer

R package officer cannot write to powerpoint slide. Layout_properties confirms field ctrTitle exists but slide_summary reports zero rows.

```
> pres<-read_pptx()
> add_slide(x=pres,layout='Title Slide', master="Office Theme")
pptx document with 1 slide(s)
Available layouts and their associated master(s) are:
             layout       master
1       Title Slide Office Theme
2 Title and Content Office Theme
3    Section Header Office Theme
4       Two Content Office Theme
5        Comparison Office Theme
6        Title Only Office Theme
7             Blank Office Theme
> ph_add_text(x=pres, type="ctrTitle", str= "This is the title")
Error: unvalid id 0 (1 slide(s))
>
```

Fields exit in layout_properties.

```
> layout_properties(x=pres, layout="Title Slide", master="Office Theme")
    master_name        name     type id                   ph_label
9  Office Theme Title Slide       dt  4         Date Placeholder 3
17 Office Theme Title Slide      ftr  5       Footer Placeholder 4
27 Office Theme Title Slide   sldNum  6 Slide Number Placeholder 5
35 Office Theme Title Slide ctrTitle  2                    Title 1
36 Office Theme Title Slide subTitle  3                 Subtitle 2
                                            ph     offx     offy       cx
9         <p:ph type="dt" sz="half" idx="10"/> 0.500000 6.951389 2.333333
17    <p:ph type="ftr" sz="quarter" idx="11"/> 3.416667 6.951389 3.166667
27 <p:ph type="sldNum" sz="quarter" idx="12"/> 7.166667 6.951389 2.333333
35                     <p:ph type="ctrTitle"/> 0.750000 2.329861 8.500000
36             <p:ph type="subTitle" idx="1"/> 1.500000 4.250000 7.000000
          cy
9  0.3993056
17 0.3993056
27 0.3993056
35 1.6076389
36 1.9166667
>
```

I tried to chain the commands; the error message is different.

```
>     pres<-read_pptx()
>     add_slide(x=pres,layout="Title Slide", master="Office Theme") %>%
+     ph_add_text(type='ctrTitle',str="This is the title")
Error: selection does not match any row in slide_summary. Use function slide_summary.
>
```

This gave me a clue.

```
> slide_summary(pres, index=1)
[1] type     id       ph_label offx     offy     cx       cy       text    
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
>
```

**slide_summary reports zero rows**. Can someone please help with this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my working code.

```r
pres <- read_pptx()
pres <- add_slide(pres, layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme")
pres <- ph_empty(pres, type = "body")
pres <- ph_add_par(pres, level = 1)
pres <- ph_add_text(pres, str = "这里是文字")
```

And I think you should consider the library magrittr.
Then it can be write as follows:

```r
library("magrittr")
pres <- read_pptx() %>%
    add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_empty(type = "body") %>%
    ph_add_par(level = 1) %>%
    ph_add_text(str = "这里是文字")
```

I see you want `Title Slide`, then you could write like this simply:

```r
pres <- read_pptx() %>%
    add_slide(layout = "Title Slide", master = "Office Theme") %>%
    ph_with_text(type = "ctrTitle", str = "这里是文字")
```

Comment: Thanks brother. I can not reproduce this result.```> ph_add_text(x=pres,str = "This be the title in slide #2")
Error: selection does match more than a single row in slide_summary. Use function slide_summary.
>

Comment: What do you mean? My code is not working? Just try my last code. It's for title slide.

Comment: sir, I am getting an error message when i do add_slide(layout = "Title and Content", master = "Office Theme") %>%
+ ph_empty(pres, type = "ctrTitle") %>% 
ph_add_text(str = "This be the title in slide #2"). The error says Error: selection does match more than a single row in slide_summary. Use function slide_summary. when i check slide_summary, it says zero rows

Comment: I know what's going wrong. You are mixing different layout.

Comment: sir, when i do "body' your code works. but not for title of the slide of layout Title and Content. What to do?